# How can i Create a wpf Datagrid view with dynamically generating combobox columns

Tags: wpf, mvvm, combobox, datagrid

How can i Create a Datagrid view with dynamically generating combobox (through c#) columns and how can i bind the data to those dynamically generated columns (through MVVM).
 i want to generate different collection of data to each combobox inside the automatically generated column.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I need to add more columns with the comboboxes to the existing datagrid in the run time dynamically of a button click action. i dont know the number of columns to add, one extra combobox column should be added in each button click and the data should be binded.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you want to add the combobox via c#.
Why not use a Template Column where you take advantage of MVVM as you should do. View is defined in XAML and content is bound via ViewModel data.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ColumnHeader">
     <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
           <DataTemplate>
                 <local:CostumControlWithCombobox Text="{Binding Path=YourListToPickFrom}"/>
           </DataTemplate>
     </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

If the pick lists should be possibly different for certain row. You need a rule or a parameter how to bind the matching list. Note that it is also possible to add controls with mvvm behavior in a TemplateColumn (just for the sake of demonstration) but you could also bind to a combobox list itself.

If you still prefer to build this up via C# code Check out the Class documentation of DataGridTemplateColumn they can also be accessed via code.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridtemplatecolumn(v=vs.110).aspx

HTH

Comment: I need to add more columns with the comboboxes to the existing datagrid in the run time dynamically of a button click action. i dont know the number of columns to add, one extra combobox column should be added in each button click and the data should be bindeed.

Comment: You should have the columns defined in your viewmodel and the databinding should handle the update of the view. So logic is in the view model and the view gets updated via binding

Comment: I dont know how many columns should be added, it should be dependent on the user at run time